# How to use Adobe Indesign API in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, add-in, adobe-indesign

I have got a sample add in for excel:
I create a object InDesign.Application

```
        Dim myInDesign As InDesign.Application
        Dim myDoc As InDesign.Document
        Dim myPage As InDesign.Page

        myInDesign = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application"), True), InDesign.Application)
        myDoc = myInDesign.Documents.Add    
        myDoc = myInDesign.ActiveDocument
```

InDesign opens, But the add-in shows error at:

```
`myInDesign = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application"), True), InDesign.Application)`
```

Content of Error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'InDesign.Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{ABD4CBB2-0CFE-11D1-801D-0060B03C02E4}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Why? Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the reference to the InDesign Type Library using vb.net's com interface?

Open the references panel in Visual Studio and choose the "COM" tab, and look for `InDesign` in your list.  It will default to `Copy Local = False`.

Now you can use the COM functions just like you were writing vbs.